# TeXstudio and viewing multiple pdf files

Tags: viewers, texstudio

I am editing two different TeX files simultaneously, the manuscript and the response for the referees, and generating pdf files through pdfLaTeX. How can I go from one pdf to another in the internal PDF viewer without recompiling the other file?

Comment: Why don't you start two instances of TeXstudio?

Comment: I need to edit one file while looking at the other as a pdf.

Comment: My TeXstudio shows the preview as a separate window. Isn't it possible to align the windows side by side? On what platform are you, which version of TeXstudio are you using?

Comment: I am on Kubuntu, using the latest TeXstudio 2.5.2. I could arrange the windows, that it seems sub-optimal to me. I feel more comfortable working in the same window.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I just found it and it is pretty easy: selecting the tab and pressing <kbd>F7</kbd> does the trick.

Comment: this does not work in windows 7 though.