# Texstudio on Mac, cannot view multiple pdf

Tags: texstudio

[Noob Alert] I am new to texstudio, having shifted from texshop due to lack of tabs and code folding.

I need to compile two (or more) documents side by side with the tabs. I am unable to view (go to pdf) for one of them if the pdf of the other is active. Using internal pdf viewer.

The solution to this question preseneted in the link below did not work for me
[TeXstudio and viewing multiple pdf files](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/104006/texstudio-and-viewing-multiple-pdf-files)

Comment: Solution provided at that one did not work for me

Comment: OK, so can you provide some more details. For example, what operating system and version of TeXstudio do you have? Also, what happens when you try the solution in the suggested dupe?

Comment: I use OSX. Texstudio 2.6.2. 
Turns out Tools --> View is what i wanted. The F7 key did not work since on my system it is used for play previous track.

Comment: On Macs you have to press the fn-key to get the Fx functionality of the key.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about use-functions that are specific to that editor rather than TeX-related functions.

Comment: @percusse: Specific questions for TeX editors are frequently asked and answered here on tex.sx.

Comment: @percusse: On the other hand the question was about an issue caused by confusion about use of keys in portable computers and essentially answered by Tim Hoffmann.

Comment: @Speravir That is true about the questions that has the minimum relation with TeX usage. This one is both a year old amd about Mac function key shortcut.