# How do I view multiple PDF outputs with TexStudio?

Tags: texstudio, windows, multiple-files

I tried the solution [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/104006/texstudio-and-viewing-multiple-pdf-files) by going to Tools->View on both files. That simply opens the currently selected tex file's output in the viewer and not both/other simultaneously. I want to view two different PDF outputs simultaneously.

I am on Windows 10 using TeXstudio 2.12.4.

---

Editing multiple files with split screen view

[image]

Comment: Why would there be two PDF outputs? Are you working with two .tex files?

Comment: @Troy Yes. I am working on two separate tex files in parallel.

Comment: @Troy See update.